# Adding data to an NSDictionary that is within another NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsdictionary

I am trying to add data to an `NSMutableDictionary` that is nested inside other Dictionaries.

**Start Output before the code that adds data is run**

```
DayData Dictionary {            //DayData Dictionary

Monday =     {                  //events Dictionary
    trip1 =         {           //eventData Dictionary
        numItems = 9items;
        time = "5:00";
        tripName = beachfucking;
    };
};
Thursday =     {
    trip1 =         {
        numItems = 9items;
        time = "5:00";
        tripName = beachfucking;
    };
};
Tuesday =     {
    trip1 =         {
        numItems = 9items;
        time = "5:00";
        tripName = beachfucking;
    };
};
Wendsday =     {
    trip1 =         {
        numItems = 9items;
        time = "5:00";
        tripName = beachfucking;
    };
};
}
```

**The code generating this output**

```
NSMutableDictionary *eventData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjects:@[@"5:00",@"9items",@"beachfucking"] forKeys:@[@"time",@"numItems",@"tripName"]];

NSMutableDictionary *event = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              eventData,@"trip1",nil];

NSMutableDictionary *dayData = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                        event,@"Monday",event,@"Tuesday",
                                        event,@"Wendsday",event,@"Thursday",nil];
```

My current try to fix the problem. Here I create a new Event `NSDictionary` then add that data to the DayData Dictionary. But the output is not correct. Every day of the week gets a "trip2" data set when Monday is only suppose to.

```
 NSMutableDictionary *event2 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              eventData,@"trip2",nil];
[[dayData objectForKey:@"Monday"] addEntriesFromDictionary:event2];
```

**Current wrong output from code above**

```
2016-12-24 01:56:41.261329 test1[10098:380349] {
    Monday =     {
        trip1 =         {
            numItems = 9items;
            time = "5:00";
            tripName = beachfucking;
        };
        trip2 =         {
            numItems = 9items;
            time = "5:00";
            tripName = beachfucking;
        };
    };
    Thursday =     {
        trip1 =         {
            numItems = 9items;
            time = "5:00";
            tripName = beachfucking;
        };
        trip2 =         {
            numItems = 9items;
            time = "5:00";
            tripName = beachfucking;
        };
    };
    Tuesday =     {
        trip1 =         {
            numItems = 9items;
            time = "5:00";
            tripName = beachfucking;
        };
        trip2 =         {
            numItems = 9items;
            time = "5:00";
            tripName = beachfucking;
        };
    };
    Wendsday =     {
        trip1 =         {
            numItems = 9items;
            time = "5:00";
            tripName = beachfucking;
        };
        trip2 =         {
            numItems = 9items;
            time = "5:00";
            tripName = beachfucking;
        };
    };
    }
```

**Notice how trip2 is filled in for all days of the week.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your all days key are contains same reference object `event`, so that changing one of it, will reflects to all the days key.

To solved the problem declare your `dayData` `Dictionary` like this.

```
NSMutableDictionary *dayData = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                [event mutableCopy] ,@"Monday",[event mutableCopy],@"Tuesday",
                                [event mutableCopy],@"Wendsday",[event mutableCopy],@"Thursday",nil];
```

Comment: Yes but i'm creating the nsdictionary object event2 then adding that to the Monday key.